# using elements of one ruby array as indices to another

Tags: ruby, arrays

In the following code, I am trying to get the indices of the occurrences of the letter `guess` in array `secret_word`, store the indices in an array `indices`, then, using `indices`, insert the same letter into another array `user_word` without disturbing the other letters that might already be in `user_word`.

```
if secret_word.include?(guess) #secret_word is an array of chars. guess is a char.
  indices = Array.new
  indices<< secret_word.each_index.select{ |letter| secret_word[letter] == guess } #verified that this array fills correctly
  indices.each do |e|
    user_word[e] = guess
  end
end
```

The error message implies that each element of indices is an array, not a fixnum as expected. It will not let me use the element from indices to index into `user_word`. Help?

Comment: You didn't say what the error message is.

Comment: Arrays are indexed by number, not objects (`.each_index` would yield `0`, `1`, ... up to the length of the array minus 1). A Hash would be referenced using objects. Is `secret_word` really an Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.select` returns an array which you are trying to add as an element to `indices` so you have an array of arrays with one element, correct way:

```
indices = secret_word.each_index.select{ |letter| secret_word[letter] == guess }
```

or

```
indices += ...
```

But I would do something like this:

```
user_word =
  user_word.split("") 
    .zip(secret_word)
    .map { |u, s| s == guess ? s : u }
    .join
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to upvote yet, so let me say "thanks!" Zip is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Playtime!

DOSRW="g`ooxdenql9qdc9uhkdo`bjq`sdcnmj9xdnqbghcdsn`rs9qdrsxkhrsdbg`hqdataak9dby`qdghbbtodonmxs`hkdl`sy"

```
def guess_the_word
  words = ''
  DOSRW.each_byte {|b| words += b.succ.chr}
  words = words.gsub('e',' ').gsub(':','e').split
  @sw = words[rand(words.size)].chars
  fini = 2**@sw.size - 1
  so_far(v=0)
  loop do
    print 'Guess a letter: '
    letter = gets.chomp.downcase
    b = @sw.inject('') {|w,c| w + (c == letter ? '1' : '0')}.to_i(2)
    b > 0 ? (puts "#{b.to_s(2).chars.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)} of those!") : (puts "Sorry")
    v |= b
    so_far(v)
    break if v == fini 
  end  
  puts "Congratulations!"  
end

def so_far(v)
  s = v.to_s(2)
  s = ((?0 * (@sw.size-s.size)) + s).chars   
  puts "#{@sw.zip(s).inject('') {|m,e| m + (e.last=='1' ? e.first : '-')}}"
end
```

Notice that I'm bit-twiddling to keep track of the positions of the currently-selected letter (`b`) and of all correctly-guessed letters so far (`y`).  The game continues until all of `y`'s bits equal one: `break if v == fini`.